# Socket created via VPN not closing

Tags: android, android-intent, vpn

I have an application that creates a Websocket connection to a server.
The app works fine so far.

Now I have the problem that the socket is not closing when the VPN connection on which it is created get destroyed.
I have, so far, not found any way to get notified of the VPN connection state change

```
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
        <action android:name="android.net.VpnService"/>
        <action android:name="vpn.connectivity"/>
```

are all not working (`android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` works fine but is not notified when the VPN connects/disconnects).

I am using Androids native IPsec support, no external VPN application.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this problem or work around it?

Comment: nope, not so far, it seems as if Android has no implemented way to get a VPN state or even check to which VPN instance the phone is connected at the time. I need this information for a corporate client so I do not have to alway try to connect even though I am not even on the right network/VPN.